# Generate MVN data that has a specific mean and variance matrix

Tags: r, regression, distributions

As an example, say I want to create a matrix $Y$ with 2 covariates and 10 observations each ( a 10 x 2 matrix) with a specific variance matrix and mean vector. The goal is to simulate regression data.

I want to generate $Y\sim MVN(\mu,\Sigma)$.  As an example:
$\Sigma =\begin{bmatrix}1 & .1 \\ .1 & 1\end{bmatrix} , $ $\mu=\begin{bmatrix}10 & 4\end{bmatrix}$

I start by generating $X\sim MVN(\vec{0},\mathbb{I})$ and my mean and variance matrix:

```
x <- matrix( rnorm(20), 10, 2)
mu <- matrix(c(10,4), nrow = 2)
sigma <- matrix( c(1,.1,.1, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

If I understand correctly what I need to do is let $Y = \mu +BX$ where $B=U\Lambda^{\frac{1}{2}}$ such that $U$ is the matrix of eigenvectors and $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix of eigen values of $\Sigma$.  So I go to compute that:

```
eigen <- eigen(sigma)
u <- eigen$vectors
sqrtlambda <- sqrt(diag(eigen$values))
B = u %*% sqrtlambda
```

But this isn't quite what I want at all, as this has all of my dimensions wrong to get what I am looking for.

Final code missing:

```
mu <- matrix(rep(1,10),nrow = 10) %*% mu
Y = x %*% t(B) + mu
```

Comment: It was just a number I came up with off the top of my head, I was thinking something along the lines of two RV X's, each with 10 replicates.

Comment: My apologies. I misread your code. The problem is that when you write $BX$ in algebra $X$ is a column vector of length 2. When you created a matrix you made it with column dimension 10. You either need to transpose your `x` or you need to redo your algebra to work with row-vectors and then compute $XB^\prime$ instead.

Comment: Ah thank you!  The continual mix of block notation had me confused.  I promise this is all on the premise of trying to learn the algebra!

Answer (score 1):

A relevant piece of code is:

```
n <- 10
p <- 2
mu <- c(10, 4)
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, .1, .1, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)

ed <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
ev <- ed$values
evec <- ed$vectors
Y <- drop(mu) + tcrossprod(evec * rep(sqrt(pmax(ev, 0)), each = p), 
                           matrix(rnorm(n * p), n))
t(Y)
```